# Terraform: Adding a specific string to an AWS instance name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

%s_%s_Instance_%s",var.tags.Env,var.tags.Cus, count.index+1

Env = Test
Cus = Demo

If I need three instances, I will get the following:

Test_Demo_Instance_1
Test_Demo_Instance_2
Test_Demo_Instance_3

Now, I want to add "Primary" to the first instance.

I want this...

Test_Demo_Instance_Primary_1
Test_Demo_Instance_2
Test_Demo_Instance_3

How can I add Primary to my Terraform code? It should reflect only the first instance.

Tried to give directly. But not applied.

Comment: Please provide actual TF code demonstrating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve this would kind of look like this -

Assuming my primary instance would be larger/different (t2.medium instead of t2.small like secondary) instance

1. I would create the first/primary instance separately

```
resource "aws_instance" "primary_instance" { }
```

2. And then using a for loop in count I would create the secondary instances resource

```
resource "aws_instance" "secondary_instance" { 
 count = ....
}
```

(just like you did)

**TLDR:** Long story short, you can just create the primary instance separately using a ec2 resource block, and create other secondary resources as much as you want using another resource block.